# before fetching data in db response is sent by node js

Tags: node.js

this is my  set notification object

```
  var sentNotificationObj = function (notification, eventid, addedorganizerpropic) {
        this.notification = notification;
        this.eventid = eventid;
        this.addedorganizerpropic = addedorganizerpropic;
    }
```

this is my array which is stored notification obect

```
var notificationSetArray2 = [];
```

this is my api of getnotification

```
router.post('/getnotification', function (req, res) {
    console.log('in aside');
    var id = req.body.userid;
    console.log('pos id' + id);
    User.findById({ _id: id }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err get notification');
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "severe error"
            });
        } else {
```

this is code fetchin data in data base

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.notification.length; i++) {
    var addedevent = result.notification[i].addedevent;
    var notification = result.notification[i].notification;
    console.log('added event' + addedevent);
    console.log('added noti' + notification);
    User.findById({ _id: result.notification[i].addedorganizer }, function (err, addedorganizer) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error get added user pofile pic');
        } else {
```

convert image to base64

```
            var base64str = base64_encode(addedorganizer.profileData.profileurl);
            console.log(base64str);
            console.log(notification);
            console.log(addedevent);
            var newsentNotificationObj = new sentNotificationObj(notification, addedevent, base64str);
            notificationSetArray2.push(newsentNotificationObj);
            console.log('succe get added user profile pic');
        }
    });
}
```

this is response

```
        res.statusCode = 200;
            res.json({
                success: true,
                notificationArray: notificationSetArray2
            })
            console.log(notificationSetArray2);
            notificationSetArray2.length = 0;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Code is half of the deal. How about some explanation on what is going on here and what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution in here to use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library here. 
Node runs code in asynchronous way. So it is natural to send response before fetching any data from your database.

By using **async** you can execute this in a sequence. So it will be solved.
Use **async.series** method for solve this. For example

```
async.series(
    [
        function(callback){
            // fetch your data here using mongo with your loop
            //
            //
            callback(); // this will trigger next step (call this after you finished iterating array)
        },
        function(callback){
            // after above code has been executed
            // send response here
            callback() // call this to proceed
        }
    ],

    function(err){
        // handle any error in here
    }
)
```

[A good example of how to use asyncjs in node](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice)